# R not recognising worksheet number 2 to add rows

Tags: r, r-googlesheets

I am trying to add data to the second worksheet of an existing Google Sheet, but the R `googlesheet` package does not seem to recognise that there are more than one worksheets already in the spreadsheet. Here are the interactive commands along with their responses.

```
gs_upload("log08.txt")
# File uploaded to Google Drive:
# log08.txt
# As the Google Sheet named:
# log08

gobj<-gs_title("log08")
# Sheet successfully identified: "log08"

gs_ws_new(ss = gobj,ws_title = "expanded")
# Worksheet "expanded" added to sheet "log08".
# Worksheet dimensions: 1000 x 26.

gs_edit_cells(ss = gobj,ws = 2,input = data_table2)
# Error: Spreadsheet only contains 1 worksheets.
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured out you have to refresh the gs handle. 
Using `gs_title` or `gs_key` register the google sheet file again and then use `gs_edit_cells` with the newly added worksheet and it will work.